# Shorter way to get the date without time in Coldfusion

Tags: datetime, coldfusion

In ColdFusion, I can get the current date without time (technically with the time set to 00:00:00) using `CreateDate()`.  This is useful for comparing two dates, irrespective of time. However, this seems inefficient. For example, to get today's date, I would write:

```
CreateDate(Year(Now()),Month(Now()),Day(Now())
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: `DateFormat(now(),'yyyy-mm-dd')` - ColdFusion is very good at reading dates from strings and can make sense of something no matter how it's formatted, as long as you call it a date. I'm sure someone will chime in with how my take isn't best practice, but it'll work if you're looking for less steps.

Comment: Interesting suggestion @TRose. I tested that and the logic works, but it runs 4 times slower with DateFormat() instead of CreateDate().  Maybe CreateDate() is the way to go after all.

Comment: You could always create a UDF that does the above. Then just use the UDF in the rest of your code.

Comment: @ale True, I was mainly thinking this must be inefficient because it's calling 4 functions - `Year()`, `Month()`, `Day()` and `CreateDate()`.  So, although a UDF would make it more efficient in the text length of the code, which is good, the number of functions would increase.

Comment: Create an UDF that at least set `now()` into a var to reduce the # of function calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `dateCompare` with a 3rd argument  of `d` to only compare the date itself

```
dateCompare(date1, date2, 'd')
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Now()` return the current time as well?

Comment: Yes, which I why I said "If you don't care about the time"

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding. However, I do care about the time, in a sense.  Comparing `Now()` to the current date should be equal. So, with today being March 3, 2017, `CreateDate(2017,3,21)` should be equal to `MissingFunction(Now())` no matter what time of day it is. So what I'm asking is for the most efficient way to write `MissingFunction()`.

Comment: You can use `dateCompare(date1, date2, 'd')`

Comment: The most efficient way to write `MissingFunction()` is with the code in your question.  Personally, I don't think it's worth the effort because to use the function, you have to either create an object or include the file with the function.

Comment: @MattBusche That's a much better solution... adding 'd' to the end of `datecompare()` makes in unnecessary to use `createdate()`. In truth, that was the root of the question.  +1

Answer (score -2):

`<cfset myVar = now()>` is the quickest way to get the current date into a variable. Yes it has the time, too, but you just ignore the time later. EX: `#dateFormat(myVar, 'short')#`, or more for your use....

`DateDiff('datepart', myVar, someOtherDateVar)`

More info: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DateDiff.html